# TeXStudio Autocomplete or suggest image path

Tags: graphics, texstudio, auto-completion

I am writing a report in TexStudio. I recently exported the report from sharelatex. In sharelatex, it autocompletes or suggests the image file location. But I can't make TeXstudio do the same thing. Do anyone no what I am doing wrong?

Since I have very many images in different folders (see picture), this is a problem.

I have no problem compiling. 
the graphics path is added using `\graphicspath{{./figure/}}`
I have also added the folder path under `adv. editor` - `additional search paths`.

Do anyone know how I can make TeXStudio autocomplete image paths.

[image: Photo over the project with many subfolders containing images]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not work on Windows: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2163/

---

To activate file completion, use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

For example, if you have a file structure like

```
.
├── demo.tex
└── figure
    ├── IMGP9039.jpg
    └── otherfigs
        └── IMGP9647.jpg
```

In `demo.tex`, you write `\includegraphics{}`, and place the cursor between the braces, like so:

[image: texstudio]

When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, you'll see this:

[image: texstudio 2]

Hit the down arrow key to select the figure folder, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it:

[image: texstudio 3]

Move through folders until you find the correct one, and select the file you're after. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, and you're done.

Comment: On a general note, different editors have different features, you can't necessarily expect that a specific feature in one editor is available in another.